# Transaction error but program returned success

Tags: pda

Regarding this tx:
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5XX4VPGzxYd8VQYdpcLmASokERwxVp8RtyqZ9Y2Kw5P5FVjSRS2dP5xpUqDqAfTrQs43wuV6A6HRs5M6QNjQh1iJ?cluster=devnet

The program logs returned success, but it was ultimately errored due to Insufficient Funds for Rent.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because my PDA had insufficiently allocated space.